# Kali in VB shows USB network adapter, but does not add it to NICS

Tags: networking, usb, virtualbox, kali-linux

so i have Kali in Virtualbox 5.0
And it detects my TP-LINK TL-WN722N as a USB device in lsusb.
[image]

I have networkmanager set to "true"
[image]

But my Kali does NOT detect it as a wireless device, which i need to pen test my own network.
[image]

I have 1 NAT interface in the VB Network settings, and i have USB Controller turned on, but i do not have any USB Device Filters added.

I tested the adapter and ISO in a live boot, and they worked perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add the usb device in VM usb config to be exclusively used by Kali.

Comment: Pls add the output of `lspci -vnn | grep -i net` and of `lshw -C network`

Comment: The issue has seemed to resolve itself? I noticed that when i plug in the device, it takes 1 of 2 names, and i only filtered 1 USB device.
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n [0108]
and
ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN [0108]
I filtered the 2 devices now and it works, thanks for the response anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has seemed to resolve itself.
I noticed that when i plug in the device, it takes 1 of 2 names, and i only filtered 1 USB device.
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n [0108] 
and
ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN [0108]
I filtered the 2 devices now and it works

(although it takes on 1 of the 2 names randomly)

[image]